# Cannot install php-mysql

Tags: php5, mysql5, phpmyadmin, centos6.6

I have a VPS with CentOS 6.6 x86-64 and ISPManager, PHP 5.4.43, Server version: 5.5.45 MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi and an version phpMyAdmin.
I upgraded php from 5.3 to 5.4 and mysql from 5.1 to 5.5.

After upgrade I cannot login to phpMyAdmin as I am redirected to my web page, and phpinfo does not show mysql section. I found that I should install php-mysql, but I cannot do it because of an  error.

I tried some suggestions but they did not help. Is problem caused by installation from different repositories ? How to solve it ?

```
[root@vps-15134 yum.repos.d]# yum list installed | grep mysql
compat-mysql51.x86_64 5.1.54-1.el6.remi @remi
mysql.x86_64          5.5.45-1.el6.remi @remi
mysql-libs.x86_64     5.5.45-1.el6.remi @remi
mysql-server.x86_64   5.5.45-1.el6.remi @remi

[root@vps-15134 yum.repos.d]# yum list installed | grep php
php-domxml-php4-php5.noarch
php-pear-DB.noarch    1.7.13-3.el6      @epel
php54w.x86_64         5.4.43-1.w6       @webtatic
php54w-cli.x86_64     5.4.43-1.w6       @webtatic
php54w-common.x86_64  5.4.43-1.w6       @webtatic
php54w-mbstring.x86_64
php54w-mcrypt.x86_64  5.4.43-1.w6       @webtatic
php54w-pdo.x86_64     5.4.43-1.w6       @webtatic
php54w-pear.noarch    1:1.9.4-7.w6      @webtatic
php54w-xml.x86_64     5.4.43-1.w6       @webtatic
[root@vps-15134 yum.repos.d]#

[root@vps-15134 yum.repos.d]# yum install php-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.mirohost.net
 * epel: ftp.colocall.net
 * extras: mirror.mirohost.net
 * remi: mirror.h1host.ru
 * remi-safe: mirror.h1host.ru
 * rpmforge: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.mirohost.net
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.44-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.44-1.el6.remi for package: php-mysql-5.4.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.44-1.el6.remi will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.44-1.el6.remi for package: php-pdo-5.4.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php54w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.43-1.w6 will be obsoleted
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.44-1.el6.remi will be obsoleting
---> Package php54w-common.x86_64 0:5.4.43-1.w6 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.43-1.w6 for package: php54w-mcrypt-5.4.43-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.43-1.w6 for package: php54w-mbstring-5.4.43-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.43-1.w6 for package: php54w-xml-5.4.43-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.43-1.w6 for package: php54w-cli-5.4.43-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.43-1.w6 for package: php54w-5.4.43-1.w6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.4.44-1.el6.remi will be obsoleting
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.44-1.el6.remi will be obsoleting
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.44-1.el6.remi will be obsoleting
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.44-1.el6.remi will be obsoleting
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.44-1.el6.remi will be obsoleting
---> Package php54w.x86_64 0:5.4.43-1.w6 will be obsoleted
---> Package php54w-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.43-1.w6 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-cli >= 5.1.0-1 for package: 1:php54w-pear-1.9.4-7.w6.noarch
---> Package php54w-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.43-1.w6 will be obsoleted
---> Package php54w-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.43-1.w6 will be obsoleted
---> Package php54w-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.43-1.w6 will be obsoleted
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:php54w-pear-1.9.4-7.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php54w-cli >= 5.1.0-1
           Removing: php54w-cli-5.4.43-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php54w-cli = 5.4.43-1.w6
           Obsoleted By: php-cli-5.4.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               Not found
           Available: php54w-cli-5.4.42-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php54w-cli = 5.4.42-1.w6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@vps-15134 yum.repos.d]#
```

Comment: I'm not an export in CentOS but have you tried removing php54w-cli-5.4.43-1.w6.x86_64 and installing php54w-cli-5.4.42-1.w6.x86_64 instead?

Comment: I agree that you should first try removing the other repositories: `yum remove remi-release`, ...

Comment: Get rid of all the webtatic RPMs and repo. It is well known to be incompatible with everything else. Then install the correct RPMs from remi. ([Why you should never use any repo except remi for PHP?](http://serverfault.com/a/702616/126632))

Comment: thanks!  I completely removed php and mysql, and issued a command as you said yum remove remi-release. Then, I followed these steps http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#prepare.